# GDAL creation option to set variable name to netCDF

Tags: gdal, netcdf, naming-conventions

Is there any way to set *variable name* in netCDF file with GDAL?
GDAL always sets the name *Band1*. I would like to set a different name. Still no success to find some -co (creation option) to overcome it.

E.g. command to rasterize a polygon

```
gdal_rasterize -a value -ot Int16 -te -180 -60 180 60 -tr 0.01 0.01 -of netCDF -co WRITE_LONLAT=YES -co TYPE_LONLAT=float -co FORMAT=NC4 -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -l input input.shp result.nc
```

Possibly, is there any other simple way to do this?

Comment: No, you can't set the name of each band (2D variable) with the NetCDF driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think that's currently possible with GDAL for netcdf. Otherwise, this would work

```
    rasterband1.setDescription("A better band name")
```

Instead you might be better off using a different command line tool such as: https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo or even with the netCDF4 library in python.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, my research until now is the same: no creation option with GDAL. Thanks @toferkey for another two hints.

Answer (score 1):

Use NCO's [ncrename](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ncrename) utility to rename the variable *Band1* to *my_var*, keeping the same filename:

```
ncrename -v Band1,my_var result.nc
```